# How to solve NoMethodError that arises due to using a same library with two different versions using gradle or anything else?

Tags: apache-spark, gradle

I have two dependencies that use a same library but with different versions and I get NoMethodError. I am not sure how to solve it using gradle or anything else? Any help would be great

```
group 'com.hello'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'idea'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    mavenLocal()
}


dependencies {
    compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:1.7.12'
    compile group: 'org.apache.spark', name: 'spark-core_2.11', version: '2.0.1'
    compile group: 'org.apache.spark', name: 'spark-streaming_2.11', version: '2.0.1'
    compile group: 'org.apache.spark', name: 'spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2.11', version: '2.0.1'
    compile group:'org.apache.kafka', name: 'kafka-clients', version: '0.10.1.0'
    compile group: 'com.datastax.spark', name: 'spark-cassandra-connector_2.11', version: '2.0.0-M3'
    compile group: 'com.github.brainlag', name: 'nsq-client', version: '1.0.0.RC2'
    compile group: 'com.google.code.gson', name: 'gson', version: '2.7'
}


task buildStreamingJar(type: Jar) {
    if(project.hasProperty("jarname")) {
        def fullyQualifiedPackageName = ""
        def jarname = project.getProperty("jarname")
        if (jarname.equalsIgnoreCase("SparkDriver1")) {
            fullyQualifiedPackageName = "com.hello.streamprocessing.app.SparkDriver1"
        }
        if (jarname.equalsIgnoreCase("SparkDriver2")) {
            fullyQualifiedPackageName = "com.hello.streamprocessing.app.SparkDriver2"
        }

        baseName = project.name + "-$jarname" + "-stream"
        from { configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) } }
        with jar
        zip64 true
        from sourceSets.test.output
        manifest {
            attributes 'Main-Class': fullyQualifiedPackageName
        }
        exclude 'META-INF/.RSA', 'META-INF/.SF', 'META-INF/*.DSA'
    }
}
```

**so what is happening here is that in my dependencies spark-core_2.11 uses 
com.google.guava:14.0.1 and nsq-client uses com.google.guava:19.0**

which is leading to the following error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.collect.Sets.newConcurrentHashSet()Ljava/util/Set;
    at com.github.brainlag.nsq.NSQProducer.(NSQProducer.java:22)
    at com.hello.streamprocessing.app.SparkDriver2.main(SparkDriver2.java:37)
```

I need to use this build.gradle file to build a FAT Uber jar so I can use it with spark-submit

Answer (score 2):

Basically you can't really solve this, if either `spark-core` or `nsq-client` is using features of `guava` that or not present in one version or the other. You can run `gradlew dependencies` which will show you how gradle resolves the version conflict on `guava`. By default it will choose version 19.0 as its the newer version. Your best chance is to use versions of your libraries that are dependent on the same version of `guava`. That is either to downgrade `nsq-client` or upgrade `spark-core` if possible.

You can exclude the transitive dependency to `guava` like this:

```
dependencies {
...
  compile (group: 'com.github.brainlag', name: 'nsq-client', version: '1.0.0.RC2') {
    exclude group: 'com.google.guava', module: 'guava'
  }
...
}
```

However this will only work if `nsq-client` is not relying on features only present in version `19.0` of guava as mentioned above.

Sadly this is a common problem especially with the `guava` library as it is used in nearly every project and the developers don't care a lot about a stable API of their library.

Your best bet is probably to try excluding `guava` from `spark-core` and give it a try and, if it's not working, to exclude it from `nsq-client` and give it a try. But even if it seems to be working at a first glance odds are good (or actually bad in your case), that you will run into similar problems during runtime of your application.

If the above is not working, you could still fork `nsq-client` and replace the problematic parts with something compatible to `guava` 14.0.1. I don't really like this option but if the developers of `nsq-client` are nice they might accept your change...

Comment: great answer! yeah since I am getting newMethodError it is clear that it is using features that are present in 19.0 but not in 14.0.1

Comment: you can see this is the line https://github.com/brainlag/JavaNSQClient/blob/master/src/main/java/com/github/brainlag/nsq/NSQProducer.java#L22 where it  says noMethodError

Comment: @user1870400 "great answer!" sarcasm?

Comment: oh man! I am a positive guy. That was indeed a great answer since your elaboration is really good.

Comment: @user1870400 just wanted to be sure as the answer will probably not solve your problem  However maybe you got some idea on your options...

Comment: I replaced guava-14.0.1.jar  with guava-19.0.jar in SPARK_HOME/jars and that seem to work ok but I am not sure if it is the right thing to do. My fear is that if Spark uses features from Guava that are only present in 14.0.1 but not in 19.0 I guess my app will break.

Comment: You could checkout the spark sources and compile against guava 19.0. If this is working chances are good that it will work with version 19.0 during runtime as well. But you will need to verify again, if you update to another version of spark at some point in time.

Answer (score 0):

One of the dependencies lib is not being downloaded. Use the latest lib of both. Use can as well use this:

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
configurations {
    compile
}
dependencies {
    compile 'dependency repo1'
    compile 'dependency repo2'
}
task libs(type: Sync) {
    from configurations.compile
    into "$buildDir/libs"
}
```

This will help download both dependencies.